# How to remove "404 - Not Found" error form network trace by configuring the supportedLocales and the fallbackLocale in app’s manifest.json file?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have three **i18n** files in my **SAP UI5** project. The files are following.

1. i18n.properties
2. i18n_de.properties
3. i18n_en.properties

We don't have any entries in the i18n_de.properties and i18n_en.properties files. We only use i18n.properties file.

When we load the application, I receive a ‘404 Not Found’ network responses for loading the following files in network tab as in the below screenshot.

1. i18n_en_DE.properties?ts=2.37.08 - 404 Error
2. Messages_en_DE.properties?ts=202205091535 - 404 Error

[image]

[image]

As per the documentations -> ([Supported Locales and Fallback Chain](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/ec753bc539d748f689e3ac814e129563.html) and [I18n with supportedLocales and fallbackLocale configuration](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/06/03/ui5ers-buzz-54-i18n-with-supportedlocales-and-fallbacklocale-configuration/)) it is mentioned that we can get rid of this 404 error in network trace.

I made the changes to manifest.json file. My changes are following:-

```
//Manifest file version
"_version": "1.33.0",
...............
...............

"sap.app": {
    "_version": "1.2.0",
    "id": "hdm",
    "type": "application",
    "i18n": {
        "bundleUrl": "i18n/i18n.properties",
        "supportedLocales": ["en","de"],
        "fallbackLocale": ""
    },
...............
...............
...............
"models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleUrl": "i18n/i18n.properties",
                "supportedLocales": ["en","de"],
                "fallbackLocale": ""
            },
            "preload": true,
            "async": true
        },
        "@i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleUrl": "i18n/i18n.properties",
                "supportedLocales": ["en","de"],
                "fallbackLocale": ""
            },
            "preload": true,
            "async": true
        },
```

Since I don't have the translation files in i18n_de.properties and i18n_en.properties. I have maintained the fallbackLocale as "" ("fallbackLocale": "").

This change still give me the 404 error in network trace.

What is wrong in this change in manifest.json file?

Can somebody help me in fixing the issue.?

Comment: Is the app running inside the Fiori launchpad? I guess this has something to do with the user settings.

Comment: Which browser are you using and what are your language settings there?

Comment: Which SAPUI5 version is the app running with?

Comment: Is the app launched with the URL parameter `sap-ui-language=...` or `sap-language=...`?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann
Yes the app is running inside Fiori launchpad.
We are using google chrome.
The UI5 version is 1.99.0
The URL parameter of app is :-
https://exampleapplication.com/sites#applicationname-Display&/account/123456789

Comment: Could you please share your "Language & Region" settings from the FLP as well as your browser language settings?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann
The FLP is manged by a central platform team. Unfortunately I don't have that information. My browser language is English.

Comment: Try running the app standalone (without FLP, with your own `index.html`) and let us know if the app still requests `Messages_en_DE.properties` and `i18n_en_DE.properties` resulting in 404

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann When I run the application in standalone(without FLP). The app is not requesting the `Messages_en_DE.properties` and `i18n_en_DE.properties`.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann
If my understanding is corrcet according to [Documentation_1](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/06/03/ui5ers-buzz-54-i18n-with-supportedlocales-and-fallbacklocale-configuration/) and [Documentation_2](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/ec753bc539d748f689e3ac814e129563.html) it is mentioned that the issue can be solved.

Comment: The mentioned documentation pages refer to a concept based on isolated UI5 app and does not necessarily consider the scenario in which the app is running inside FLP. FLP and even some legacy systems, however, allow each one of users to configure their language and region when using apps on FLP. If the app has an issue only in FLP, that issue needs to be addressed and analyzed by SAP employees. I'd suggest creating a customer ticket so that FLP devs can take a look.

Comment: Did you create a customer incident? If the incident is resolved, could you please add an answer and accept it in order to let others know that the issue fixed?

Comment: I was investigating on this issue. My findings were reported back to the colleagues.

Comment: @GeoJoseph Im facing exactly the same issue. I was wondering if you were able to find a solution after your investigation. Regards, Nizare